# Is there a way to use google test on OOP program?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm new to google test and currently I'm writing a test for my OOP program, my OOP program is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int NUM;
class Employee
{

protected:
            NUM MaSoThue;
private:
            NUM Luong;
            NUM CMND;
            NUM a;
            NUM b;
public:
            Employee()
            {
                        MaSoThue = 0;
                        Luong = 0;
                        CMND = 0;
            }
            Employee(NUM mst, NUM luong, NUM cmnd)
            {
                        MaSoThue = mst;
                        Luong = luong;
                        CMND = cmnd;
            }
            //get
            int getMaSoThue() const { return MaSoThue; }
            int getLuong() const { return Luong; }
            int getCMND() const {return CMND;}
  
  //set
  void setMaSoThue(NUM mst) {if (MaSoThue==0) MaSoThue = mst;}
  void setLuong(NUM luong) {Luong = luong;}
  void setCMND(NUM cmnd) {if (CMND==0) CMND = cmnd;}
};

int main()
{
            // Objects
            Employee PhucTri(111,222,333);
            Employee MinhDang;
  MinhDang.setMaSoThue(1234);
  MinhDang.setLuong(2);
  MinhDang.setCMND(8888);
  
            //PhucTri
            cout <<"MST cua Phuc Tri: "<< PhucTri.getMaSoThue()<<"\n";
            cout << "Luong cua Phuc Tri: " << PhucTri.getLuong() << "\n";
            cout << "CMND cua Phuc Tri: " << PhucTri.getCMND() << "\n\n";
  
            //MinhDang
            cout << "MST cua Minh Dang: " << MinhDang.getMaSoThue() << "\n";
            cout << "Luong cua Minh Dang: " << MinhDang.getLuong() << "\n";
            cout << "CMND cua Minh Dang: " << MinhDang.getCMND() << "\n";
}
```

I created a new file, which is below:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "FileCode.cc"
int main(){}
TEST(No1, PhucTri){
  EXPECT_EQ(PhucTri.getMaSoThue(),111);
}
```

The compiler says that the object "PhucTri" isn't declared in this scope, but I did create it in my first file, is there any way I can get it right on the object ?

Comment: You forgot to declare the object `PhucTri` like in `main` in the first file.

Comment: Don't include `.cc` files from other `.cc` files. At minimum, you've already violated the one-definition rule with those two conflicting `main` definitions, and you'll only encounter more problems like that.

Comment: @273K I have tried to declare in main of the 2nd file, but my IDE still reports a problem.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thank you for your advice about the header file, I have tried to change the file to .h file, the problem still encounter, is there other way I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: It's not altogether clear to me what you *want* to happen. `PhucTri` is a local variable defined in a *different* function, so the test has no access to it. If you want the test to have access to it, you need to initialize the local variable *in* that function. If every C++ variable was global, we'd never be able to write anything nontrivial without it being a massive mess.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Try to not include `.cpp` files, declare your class and its methods inside a `.h` file, define methods in `.cpp` and then create a test file that includes your header.
You have two options here, either define a test class that has an instance of your class follows instructions [here](https://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html#same-data-multiple-tests).

Or do something like this :

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "FileCode.h"
TEST(No1, PhucTri)
{
    Employee PhucTri(111,222,333);
    // initialize your data 
   // ......
    EXPECT_EQ(PhucTri.getMaSoThue(),111);
}
```